# Regex Replace repeated captures

Tags: c#, sql, regex, nhibernate, log4net

I'm creating a `log4net` appender that generates `NHibernate` SQL scripts ready for execution.

I want to use Regex to replace log4net's output to a ready for use script.
A sample input would be

```
command 5:UPDATE [PlanParameter] SET Mode = @p0, DefaultValueString = @p1, ParameterID = @p2 WHERE ID = @p3;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int16 (0)], @p1 = '0' [Type: String (4000)], @p2 = 2 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p3 = 1362 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Which I want to replace with

```
UPDATE [PlanParameter] SET Mode = 1, DefaultValueString = '0', ParameterID = 2 WHERE ID = 1362
```

I have created the following Regex:

```
command \d+:(?<Query>(?:(?<PreText>[\w\s\[\]]+ = )(@p\d+)(?<PostText>,?))+);(?<Parameters>(?:@p\d+ = ('?\w+'?) \[Type: \w+ \(\d+\)\],? ?)+)
```

which matches and captures my samples perfectly:

[image: Expresso matches output]

I wanted the entire replacement to be handled by the Regex engine.  I thought I can use a replacement string such as this:

```
${PreText}$2${PostText}
```

but that only yields the last capture, and not my final goal.

In the meantime I've used C# to make it happen:

```
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"command \d+:(?<Query>(?:(?<PreText>[\w\s\[\]]+ = )(@p\d+)(?<PostText>,?))+);(?<Parameters>(?:@p\d+ = ('?\w+'?) \[Type: \w+ \(\d+\)\],? ?)+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    string sample = @"command 5:UPDATE [PlanParameter] SET Mode = @p0, DefaultValueString = @p1, ParameterID = @p2 WHERE ID = @p3;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int16 (0)], @p1 = '0' [Type: String (4000)], @p2 = 2 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p3 = 1362 [Type: Int32 (0)]";
    Match match = reg.Match(sample);
    string result = match.Groups["Query"].Value;
    for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups[1].Captures.Count; i++)
    {
        Capture capture = match.Groups[1].Captures[i];
        result = result.Replace(capture.Value, match.Groups[2].Captures[i].Value);
    }
```

This works perfectly but I'm sure there's a more clean and neat way of doing this.  Maybe with a different Regex expression perhaps?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for experimenting with CaptureCollection :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more compact regex approach:

Search: `= (@p\d+)(?=.*?\1 (= [^\[]+))|;(?!.*= @p\d).*`

Replace: `${2}`

This substitutes all the parameters with their values and erases the end of the string.

See the Substitution pane at the bottom of the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/10).

**Output:**

```
command 5:UPDATE [PlanParameter] SET Mode = 1 , DefaultValueString = '0' , ParameterID = 2 WHERE ID = 1362
```

**Sample C#**

```
String replaced = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"= (@p\d+)(?=.*?\1 (= [^\[]+))|;(?!.*= @p\d).*", "${2}");
```

**Explanation**

- The parentheses in `(@p\d+)` capture `@p` and digits to Group 1
- The lookahead `(?=.*?\1 (= [^\[]+))` asserts that what follows is...
- `.*?` match any chars up to...
- `\1` what was matched by Group 1 (e.g. `@p0`)
- The parentheses in `(= [^\[]+))` capture to Group 2 the literal `=`, all chars that are not a `[` (which we're using as a delimiter to know when your value ends. This is your value
- OR... `|` we'll also match the end of the string, and since there is no Group 2 when it is matched, the replacement `${2}` will nix it
- `;` semi-colon
- For safety, the negative lookahead `(?!.*= @p\d)` asserts that what follows is not any chars then `= @p` + digit
- `.*` matches a semi-colon and all chars to the end of the string
- The replacement string `${2}` is `=` and Group 2 (the value)

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)
- [Everything about Regex Capture Groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)

Comment: Wow thanks, exactly what I was searching for!  I'm quite a novice with Regex and I'll study yours carefully :)